# MD5 does not exists in System.Security.Cryptography namespace

Tags: c#, silverlight, md5

I utilise Visual Studio 2010 to write a simple application in C# (with silverlight) to obtain MD5 code from a string.
I included *System.Security.Cryptography* but I have the error such as in the title.
Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a reason to choose MD5 over a modern hash algorithm?

Comment: Hi, my only intention is to offer an MD5 encoding and not a valid method of encryption

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MD5` class is only available in the .NET framework, not in Silverlight. If you absolutely must use MD5 it will have to be through an externally developed MD5 implementation such as [this one](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMD5).

Preferably, if this is an option for you, consider using [`SHA1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1) instead. SHA1 is both a more secure hash function (MD5 is really not considered secure by today's standards) *and* available in Silverlight.

Comment: Hi, my only intention is to offer an MD5 encoding and not a valid method of encryption.

Comment: Both MD5 and SHA1 are neither encodings nor methods of encryption. Anyway, if you need MD5 then you will have to grab an implementation such as the linked one.

Comment: I tried to use MD5.cs class but I don't know how I can import/use this class. Please, can you give an example? Thanks.