# CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider") Fails on home PC works on Work PC

Tags: excel, vba

The following Single line of executable code;

.. Works on my work PC (Win10 Pro 21H1)

.. Crashes on my home laptop (Win 10 Pro 21H1)

Exact same version of Excel on each machine and signed in using the same account

```
Public Sub Tester()
  Dim oEnc As Object
  
  Set oEnc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")
End Sub
```

Error as per image below

[image]

I don't recall having to add a specific Reference in VBA Project to get this to work (and don't see any in the references list either). Any help appreciated

Both 64 Bit Office & Same Versions as below
[image]

Comment: Does your home computer have dotNet installed  ? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: @CDP1802 Wasn't sure, followed your link, installed & rebooted - same problem. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: It might be  .Net Framework according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171637/md5-does-not-exists-in-system-security-cryptography-namespace

Comment: @CDP1802 I've read lots of postings saying it's not possible many from several years ago (9 years for that link) ... but it clearly works - on my work PC (2 years old). Thanks again.

Comment: Will use some external MD5 routine if I have to but would prefer to findout what is causing this - affects SHA as well

Comment: From the back of my head: Maybe an 32Bit-/64Bit-Office issue? Maybe Feature `.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)` has to be activated in Windows 10?

Comment: @Unhandled Exception Both PCs 64Bit I'll try the older Frameworks thanks

Comment: Both 64bit **Office**?

Comment: The work PC it works on has 2.0, 3.0 & 3.5 .Net Frameworks as well as 4 - so I'll be busy for a while :-)

Comment: @Unhandled Exception Yes, both 64Bit Office

Comment: @Unhandled Exception You were correct, I installed .NET Framework 3.5 (Includes 2.0 + 3.0) and problem has gone away. Thanks for Help, much appreciated.

Comment: I will prepare an anwser to have other searching developers finding the solution easier.

Comment: @Unhandled Exception - Good - Happy to accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 10 you will have to activate the feature `.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)`.